# How to calculate percentage of english words in a paragraph using Python

Tags: python, character, word-count

Let's say that I have a paragraph with different languages in it. like:

`This is paragraph in English. 这是在英国段。Это пункт на английском языке. این بند در زبان انگلیسی است.`

I would like to calculate what percentage (%) of this paragraph includes English words. So would like to ask how to do that in python.

Comment: You have to first figure out that How would your computer know what is english and what is russian? :)

Comment: You might want to try http://www.nltk.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This offline solution uses the pyenchant spellcheck module:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import enchant
dictionary = enchant.Dict("en_US")

paragraph = u"This is paragraph in English. 这是在英国段。Это пункт на английском языке. این بند در زبان انگلیسی است."

words = paragraph.split(" ")
en_count = 0.0
for word in words:
  if dictionary.check(word.strip()):
    en_count += 1

percent = en_count/len(words) if len(words) != 0 else 0
print str(percent) + "% english words"
```

**Output:**

```
31.25% english words
```

Comment: Requires a tricky compilation of a heavy library, and still fails to detect the Chinese words as being separate, so I don't see the value of this. See my answer for a solution that only uses core Python.

Comment: Yeah, `pip install pyenchant` fails with `ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found. Please install it via your OS package manager, or use a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI.`. That is an uncommonly bad ("tricky") design. Even after installing this magical C library, the language packs have to be downloaded too ("heavy").

Comment: How about installing it over the OS package manager, like it is told in the traceback. All in all it is a possible solution. So you shouldn't donvote it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have qualified my comment with "unless one is already using this library". If not, then I still don't see the value because it fails to detect the Chinese words as being separate.

Comment: I installed this module just for this question. Nothing complicated, could've been done by a not so smart chicken. So I wasn't already using this library. To detect the chinese words, you could easily adjust the code (almost a two-liner). But I guess the OP was just fine with it. Otherwise he would not have marked my answer as the right solution.

Comment: I know :) The lack of details on the requirements of word counting irritates me.

Answer (score 3):

First, [get a list of English words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/741003/823470). Then, iterate through the file and count!

```
import string
import urllib2

punctuation = set(string.punctuation)

eng_words_url = 'https://raw.github.com/eneko/data-repository/master/data/words.txt'
eng_words = urllib2.urlopen(eng_words_url).readlines()
eng_words = [w.strip().lower() for w in eng_words]

def remove_punc(str):
    return ''.join(c for c in str if c not in punctuation)

total_count = 0
eng_count = 0
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = remove_punc(line).lower().split()
        total_count += len(words)
        eng_count += sum(1 for word in words if word.lower() in eng_words)

print '%s English words found' % eng_count
print '%s total words found' % total_count

percentage_eng = 0 if total_count == 0 else (float(eng_count) / total_count * 100)
print '%s%% of words were English' % percentage_eng
```

For example, this is your sample text:

> This is paragraph in English. 这是在英国段。Это пункт на английском языке.
> این بند در زبان انگلیسی است.

When I ran the above code on that, the output was this:

> 5 English words found
>
> 16 total words found
>
> 31.25% of words were English

As pointed out in the comments, the percentage is incorrect due to the Chinese words not having spaces between them. There are 22 words total so the percentage should really be 22.7%.

Comment: there are six chinese words, how are you calculating them?

Comment: Don't have to in this case because the only words that matter for this count are the English ones. If a future requirement needed a count of the Chinese words, yes the concept of a word would need to change in the code

Comment: so total does not matter for percentage no?

Comment: Ahh of course, true. Yeah, that percentage could become the most complicated part of the program.

Comment: There are actually seven words when translated, I think if you really wanted to do something like this it would be a hell of a lot more complicated.

Comment: It seems to make more sense to count words in the original language, not after translating to English. There would be so many ways to translate each particular phrase.

Comment: either way to do it accurately, it is rather more complex

Comment: Thank you dear @tar for giving a really creative solution. That solves the problem indeed

Comment: How to do it using Java?

Answer (score 3):

Some posters have found that there are 16 words in the paragraph. But are there? One of the problems is that it's difficult to use only an English language approach if you want to compare the number of English words to the words in the sentence. It's "relatively" easy to find the number of English words, but second part, i.e. to find the number of total words in the sentence, is more difficult because you need resources to disambiguate how many words are contained in 这是在英国段, in order to find the English words as a percentage of words in the paragraph.

Try using the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/). The NLTK is a Python library (Python3.0 compatibility in the works) that has built-in-functions for exactly what you're looking for (frequency of occurrence of words, tokenizing strings, etc), plus access to English language corpora that you could use to compare the words to, if you want to find the English words by comparing the words in the sentence against the words contained in the corpora.

The accompanying book *Natural Language Processing with Python*, 1 edition for Python 2.x is available for free online from the NLTK website. It serves as an introduction to both the NLTK Library and Python programming in general. The Wordlist Corpus or Roget's Thesaurus Corpus might be useful. There is also the  that detects language text. For mixed language cases, not sure how that would work.

Comment: I'm not sure NLTK does any better at counting Chinese words. I tried `import nltk; len(nltk.Text('这是在英国段'))` and it output `18`. That's no better than if I had just asked for `len('这是在英国段')` without NLTK at all.

Comment: You're right, `len` doesn't work for Chinese. I had added the first paragraph after I wrote the rest. But NLTK 2.0 has a module `nltk.tag.stanford` for interfacing with the [Stanford POS tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml), which contains a tagger model for Chinese, written in Java. Part-of-speech tagging is overkill for the project at hand, but it could serve the trick of first tokenizing the Chinese into words.

Answer (score 0):

If all your words written in latin letters are in English you could use regular expressions.

Comment: It's NOT Arabic. It is Persian. They're distinct languages.

Comment: it doesn't really matter if it is arabic or persian. if there isn't any other languages that use ASCII present than English you can just check the characters and determine the percentage that way

Comment: @Pownyan It's still false data. However it's edited now and that looks better! (:

Answer (score 0):

One helpful data structure for doing this sort of thing is a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

If we use my fork of the english word list in the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25012472/6114445):

```py
import os
import json
import urllib3
 
eng_trie = {}

def add_to_trie(trie: dict, word: str, lower: bool=False) -> dict:
    if lower:
        word = word.lower()
    letter = word[:1]

    if len(word) == 1:
        # This is the last letter, add a terminator
        trie[word] = {**trie.get(word, {}), "EOW": True}
    else:
        if not trie.get(letter):
            trie[letter] = {}
        trie[letter] = add_to_trie(trie[letter], word[1:])
    return trie

if __name__ == "__main__":
    output_file = "./data/words.json"
    url = "https://github.com/JonathanRys/data-repository/blob/master/data/words.txt?raw=true"
    response = urllib3.request("GET", url)
    if response.status:
        for word in [word.strip() for word in response.data.decode().split('\n')]:
            if word:
                try:
                    add_to_trie(eng_trie, word, lower=True)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'ERROR for word "{word}": {e}')
    
    with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
        print(json.dumps(eng_trie), file=f)
```

Then to use it

```py
import json

json_trie = './data/words.json'

def get_data(file: str) -> dict:
    with open(file) as f:
        trie = json.loads(f.read())
    return trie

def check(word: str, trie: dict=get_data(json_trie)) -> bool:
    if len(word) == 1:
        if trie.get(word):
            if trie.get(word).get('EOW'):
                return True
        else:
            return False
    if trie:
        next_trie = trie.get(word[:1])
        if next_trie:
            return check(word[1:], next_trie)
    return False

def is_english(word: str) -> bool:
    if not word:
        return False
    return check(word)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = ['albatross', 'run', 'winner', 'success', 'erwrtwaf', 'albat']
    for word in words:
        if is_english(word):
            print(f'English: {word}')
        else:
            print(f'Not English: {word}')
```